# How can I run a function that calls an Apex Method, inside the input validation function?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I need to save the user input (signature as a file, by calling an Apex Method) when the user clicks the standard "next" button in the flow screen, I am using [user input validation for flow screens](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_validate_user_input_for_custom_components), so whenever I click next, I get the validation message telling me there's no signature, because the imported function returns a promise.

Basically, I'm trying to save the user input in the validation function, but I can't because of the async processing.

How can I tackle this?

What I tried:

Enclosing the saving signature logic inside a delay function:

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second
setTimeout(function() {
    // Call Apex method logic
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to just show a spinner until the action of your Apex logic is executed successfully. The spinner will indicate that some processing is happening and the overlay of the spinner will hide the `Next` button.

```
@api
validate() {
    // Call Apex method logic
    callApexMethod().then(data => {
        //stop showing Spinner
    }).catch(error => {
        //stop showing Spinner
    })
}
```

I have never tried async await on `validate`, but try this one too and check.

```
@api
async validate() {
    // Call Apex method logic
    const result2 = await callApexMethod({
        anyParam: anyParamValue
    });

    // return true or false from apex.
    if(/* true conditions from result2*/) {
        return { isValid: true };
    }
    else {
        // If the component is invalid, return the isValid parameter 
        // as false and return an error message. 
        return {
            isValid: false,
            errorMessage: '/*A message that explains what went wrong.*/'
        };
    }
}
```